# Erlang: syntax error before: ","word"

Tags: erlang, syntax-error

I have the following functions:

```
search(DirName, Word) ->
  NumberedFiles = list_numbered_files(DirName),
  Words = make_filter_mapper(Word),
  Index = mapreduce(NumberedFiles, Words, fun remove_duplicates/3),
  dict:find(Word, Index).

list_numbered_files(DirName) ->
  {ok, Files} = file:list_dir(DirName),
  FullFiles = [ filename:join(DirName, File) || File <- Files ],
  Indices = lists:seq(1, length(Files)),
  lists:zip(Indices, FullFiles). % {Index, FileName} tuples

make_filter_mapper(MatchWord) ->
  fun (_Index, FileName, Emit) ->
    {ok, [Words]} = file:consult(FileName), %% <---- Line 20
    lists:foreach(fun (Word) ->
      case MatchWord == Word of
        true -> Emit(Word, FileName);
        false -> false
      end
    end, Words)
  end.

remove_duplicates(Word, FileNames, Emit) ->
  UniqueFiles = sets:to_list(sets:from_list(FileNames)),
  lists:foreach(fun (FileName) -> Emit(Word, FileName) end, UniqueFiles).
```

However, when i call search(Path_to_Dir, Word) I get:

```
Error in process <0.185.0> with exit value:
{{badmatch,{error,{1,erl_parse,["syntax error before: ","wordinfile"]}}},
 [{test,'-make_filter_mapper/1-fun-1-',4,[{file,"test.erl"},{line,20}]}]}
```

And I do not understand why. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The `Words` variable will match to content of the list, which might not be only one tuple, but many of them. Try to match `{ok, Words}` instead of `{ok, [Words]}`.

Comment: Though that's not the error he's getting. The call to file:consult() returns {error, ...}, not {ok, ...}, so there's a syntax error in the file he's reading.

Answer (score 0):

Beside the fact that the `function file:consult/1` may return a list of several elements so you should replace `{ok,[Words]}` (expecting a list of one element = Words) by `{ok,Words}`, it actually returns a syntax error meaning that in the file you are reading, there is a syntax error.

Remember that the file should contain only valid erlang terms, each of them terminated by a dot. The most common error is to forget a dot or replace it by a comma.